# App for previewing hair cut from a reputable source

Tags: android, android-app

I'm searching for an android app for previewing my hair cut, it not needs to be necessarly realtime but it would be better.

I'm a bit reluctant to cut my hair right now so I would like to try it virtually, the only problem is that the only ones I find online are some random fishy developers ones.

Just searching one built by a reputable developer that will not send my picture on the web or infect my phone.

Can you guys help me find a reputable one? thanks!

PS: I could photoshop a lot but the result would not be the same ;\ and it would be terribly time consuming.